# QuerySet ot Manager

Tags: python, django

In which cases preferable use Manager, and which QuerySet?
What is better:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    objects =  MyManager()
```

or:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    objects = MyQuerySet.as_manager()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34398284/django-custom-manager-and-queryset

Answer (score 1):

In most and common cases you use the first approach:

```
class Model(models.Model):
objects =  MyManager()
```

Only when you define custom QuerySet methods which you want in your manager too, you use the second approach

```
class Model(models.Model):
objects = MyQuerySet.as_manager()
```

which creates a manager with [almost](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#creating-manager-with-queryset-methods) all the methods of the custom QuerySet.